# Adding MVPlaceSearchTextField to a view programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, google-places-api, ios10

I'm using the example project and I've been trying to add the MVPlaceSearchTextField to the my ViewController programmatically.The textfield appears but always having dataSource exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An autocomplete datasource must implement either autoCompleteTextField:possibleCompletionsForString: or autoCompleteTextField:possibleCompletionsForString:completion
```

Here is my code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MVPlaceSearchTextField *txtPlaceSearch;


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _txtPlaceSearch=[[MVPlaceSearchTextField alloc]init];
    _txtPlaceSearch.frame=CGRectMake(20, 20, 300, 40);
    _txtPlaceSearch.delegate=self;
    _txtPlaceSearch.placeSearchDelegate                 = self;
    _txtPlaceSearch.strApiKey                           = @"";
    _txtPlaceSearch.superViewOfList                     = self.view;  // View, on which Autocompletion list should be appeared.
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteShouldHideOnSelection   = YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.maximumNumberOfAutoCompleteRows     = 5;

}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    //Optional Properties
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteRegularFontName =  @"HelveticaNeue-Bold";
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteBoldFontName = @"HelveticaNeue";
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableCornerRadius=0.0;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteRowHeight=35;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableCellTextColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.131 alpha:1.000];
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteFontSize=14;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableBorderWidth=1.0;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableBorderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _txtPlaceSearch.showTextFieldDropShadowWhenAutoCompleteTableIsOpen=YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteShouldHideOnSelection=YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteShouldHideClosingKeyboard=YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteShouldSelectOnExactMatchAutomatically = YES;
    _txtPlaceSearch.autoCompleteTableFrame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-_txtPlaceSearch.frame.size.width)*0.5, _txtPlaceSearch.frame.size.height+70.0, _txtPlaceSearch.frame.size.width, 200.0);
    [self.view addSubview:_txtPlaceSearch];
}
```

Comment: Did you confirm it's `Delegate`? Like `@interface ViewController : UIViewController<PlaceSearchTextFieldDelegate>`

Comment: yes @Piyush Patel